# Bulk update multiple records of multiple columns of multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have multiple tables, for example

- `TableA` with columns `AccountID, ColumnNameA1, ColumnNameA2, ColumnNameA3`)
- `TableB` with columns `AccountID, ColumnNameB1, ColumnNameB2, ColumnNameB3`
- `TableC` with columns `AccountID, ColumnNameC1, ColumnNameC2, ColumnNameC3`

I have data as shown below, I want to write a stored procedure to bulk update data according to the above mentioned tables in one go for all the columns with all the values on all of the mentioned `AccountID`. `AccountID` is a foreign key for all the tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seH25.png)

I cannot hardcode the table names in the stored procedure, since their names might change or new columns might be added to the table

I also have a stored procedure from which I am getting the list of column names and their table names in my API method.

I have to do the bulk update by using dynamic update query

```
SET @SqlText = ' UPDATE ' + @OriginalTableName + '' + 
               ' SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = ''' + @ColumnValue +
               ''' WHERE AccountID = ' + @AccountID + '   '
```

I am expecting that the stored procedure should update columns, ColumnNameA2 and ColumnNameC1 values in the table for the given `AccountID` in one go.

Comment: "I cannot hardcode the table names in SP, since their names might change or new columns might be added to the table" sounds like a bad idea. Why is your schema changing like that, why would you not know in advance what your column names are? If you are trying to write a generic "Update Any Table" procedure, don't do it because it's a bad idea. Just write a procedure for each tabel you want to update.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, even i also feel strange about column names not fixed but its business point of view. Actually on UI i am having a dx-datagrid in which values are coming more than 300 columns whose data are coming from 11 different tables based on joins on one unique id. So the user might update data of any column and on any row. so in that case if i can create update query for each table then please guide me with that.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, to achieve your goal of updating multiple tables with dynamic column names and values, you can use dynamic SQL within a stored procedure. Here's an example of how you can create such a stored procedure:

**SQL :**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateColumns
(
    @AccountID INT,
    @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255),
    @ColumnValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255)

    -- Determine the table name based on the provided column name
    IF @ColumnName IN ('ColumnNameA1', 'ColumnNameA2', 'ColumnNameA3')
        SET @TableName = 'TableA'
    ELSE IF @ColumnName IN ('ColumnNameB1', 'ColumnNameB2', 'ColumnNameB3')
        SET @TableName = 'TableB'
    ELSE IF @ColumnName IN ('ColumnNameC1', 'ColumnNameC2', 'ColumnNameC3')
        SET @TableName = 'TableC'
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Handle the case where the column name doesn't match any known tables/columns
        PRINT 'Invalid column name'
        RETURN
    END

    -- Build the dynamic SQL update statement
    SET @SqlText = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
                   ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + ' = @ColumnValue ' +
                   ' WHERE AccountID = @AccountID'

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlText, N'@AccountID INT, @ColumnValue NVARCHAR(MAX)', @AccountID, @ColumnValue
END
```

*In this stored procedure:
It takes the **AccountID**, **ColumnName**, and **ColumnValue** as parameters.
It determines the table name based on the provided column name.
It constructs a dynamic SQL update statement using the **@TableName**, **@ColumnName**, and @ColumnValue.
It uses the **sp_executesql** system stored procedure to execute the dynamic SQL with parameters **@AccountID** and **@ColumnValue**.
You can call this stored procedure with the AccountID, ColumnName, and ColumnValue you want to update, and it will update the appropriate table and column dynamically based on the input. Just make sure to handle invalid column names or other potential errors as needed.*

Comment: Hi @Mxit, thanks for your response. I want to update multiple records of multiple columns for multiple tables in single go when i execute the stored procedure.  In the above query i can pass only single values for column name and account id. But since i am having multiple values for table name, column name and account id, so it will not be feasible for me to call the above query each time for every single record.